# Passing `Set /p _var=/irc:` when used by findstr, the colon does not get processed the same as if I typed `findstr /irc:` Example provided

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, regex, escape-characters, findstr

I have search through the [undocumented 'findstr' thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman), [SS64 findstr-escapes](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html) as well as [SS64, Escape Characters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) for how to include the colon in the following way; no luck with either.

Example batch snip:

> @echo off
> Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM I want the colon within !/ipc! so the user would not need to remember and enter it, in order to comply with `findstr /irc:`.

`set ipc=/irc:` nor `set "ipc=/irc:"`is helping, when the following is used. Below, `set /p ipc1=` will have a RegEx entered by the user: `" 7_20"`, does not work. When I `@echo !ipc!`, the value properly displays, but will not get processed, nor will it find --> 23_Channel 7_20240302133900.

Currently I've had to use `set ipc=/irc` which forces the user to enter `:" 7_20"`.  The positional Args feeding `for /D  %%i in` are ?yyymmdd

> set /p ipc1=IPC?
> set /p ipc2=IPC?
>
> for /D  %%i in (%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9) do (
>
> for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b %%i ^| findstr !ipc!!ipc1! !ipc!!ipc2! 2^> nul') do (
>
> copy /y "%%i%%A" _copies
> @echo "%%i%%A"
> set fn=%%A
> set sdir=%%i
>
> )
> )

@comp much thanks for getting me this far. The feedback I'm hoping for is documentation explaining how to use and/or include the a colon with the `set /p` demonstrated above, to allow `findstr` to properly digest it.

Respectfully